# How to use `Console.WriteLine` properly

Tags: c#

I want to show the full equation `1 + 2 = 3`.

My attempt so far :

```
        double x = 1, y = 2; 
        double add = x + y ;
        Console.WriteLine(add);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Though, this gives me only `3` as output! any suggestions

Comment: Why would you need to use C# when CMD already allows you to do basic math: `set /a 1 + 2`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine(x+" + "+y+" = "+add);
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` accepts formatting on the string input in case you didn't know.

Comment: WOW! OMG You saved my life with this crucial information!! really don't know how to thank you dude?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, add)
```

chouaib's answer is also valid, if you favor string concatenation over substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
double x = 1, y = 2; 
string add = String.Format("{0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, x + y);
Console.WriteLine(add);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like you're asking us to do a homework question, so I won't post the exact code (which is left as an exercise for you), but check out the [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) method. Use it to build a string containing the equation with placeholders replaced with the variables, and then pass that string to Console.WriteLine

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you only wrote `Console.WriteLine(add)` which instructs the program to display only the "add" value.

Try this code:

```
double x = 1, y = 2; 
        double add = x + y ;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, add.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

- I added placeholders, {0}, {1} and {2} to make the code simpler.
- I also added ".ToString()" which is a good practice when you are displaying non-string data to the console.